# Python Calculator (time) appears to be giving incorrect answers

Tags: python, math

I'm making a time calculator, and I'm having trouble with calculating speed. When I input the miles and hours for it without decimals, it works just fine. But when I have decimals, its giving me the wrong answer.

```
def distance():
    mph = int(input('Input how many mph your going at '))
    start = input('Was hours or minutes given? (input hr or min) ')
    if start == "hr":
        hours = int(input('Input hour(s) '))
        e = mph*hours
        print(f'Distance is {e}')
    elif start == "min":
        minutes = int(input('Input minutes '))
        ma = minutes/60
        ans = ma*mph
        print(f'Distance is {ans}')
    else:
        print('An error has occured. Please restart program')

def speed():
    miles = int(float(input('Input miles ')))
    hours = int(float(input('Input hours ')))
    answer = miles/hours
    print(f'The speed is {answer}')


def main():
    question = input('What would you like to find? (type distance, speed, or travel) ')
    if question == "distance":
        distance()
    elif question == "speed":
        speed()
    elif question == "travel":
        print('hi')



    mph = int(input('Input how many mph your going at '))
    hours = print('Input hours (type min if you have minutes) ')
    answer = mph*hours
    print(f'Distance travled is {answer}')
    if hours == "min":
        minuets = int(input('Input minuets'))
        times = minuets/mph
        print(times)
        #print(f'Distance travled {minuets}')




main()
```

I'm trying to divide 787.5 by 3.5, and the answer it should be giving me is 225, yet it's giving me 262.3333333333333. Is something wrong with my code?

Thanks!

Comment: `int(3.5)` is 3.

Comment: `int(float(input('Input miles ')))` why are you converting a string to a float and then to an int?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def speed():
    miles = float(input('Input miles '))  # Remove the 'int' at the start
    hours = float(input('Input hours '))  # Remove the 'int' at the start
    answer = int(miles/hours)
    print(f'The speed is {answer}')


#What would you like to find? (type distance, speed, or travel) speed
#Input miles 787.5
#Input hours 3.5
#The speed is 225
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is because you're converting both inputs to floats, and then ints. `int(787.5)` is `787` and `int(3.5)` is `3`. If you type those numbers into a calculator you'll see `787/3` gets you the result you're seeing.

Leave the input as a float.